# Stack shadowed dependencies

Tags: haskell-stack

I converted a project from cabal new-build to stack. While it works on most machines, on one machine I get the shadowed dependencies problem:

```
Building library for PSS-0.2.0.0..
    <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id conduit-extra-1.3.0- 
IqE5lCHhGFAGyZP27mhAWv: 
    conduit-extra-1.3.0-IqE5lCHhGFAGyZP27mhAWv is unusable due to 
    shadowed dependencies:
        streaming-commons-0.1.19-2BxOAPRD0RODtVLE2OYQW2
    (use -v for more information)
```

From what I know, this problem should have been fixed in stack already, but on this one installation it still happens.

Stack version:

```
Version 1.6.5, Git revision 24ab0d6ff07f28276e082c3ce74dfdeb1a2ca9e9 
(5514 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.20.0
```

Cabal was installed with stack itself, version:

```
> which cabal
/home/oswald/.local/bin/cabal
> cabal --version
cabal-install version 2.0.0.1
compiled using version 2.0.1.1 of the Cabal library
```

It uses the system-installed ghc (ghc 8.2.2) and lts-11.4. It works on openSuSE LEAP 42.3 and interestingly it works best on SLES 11 (which is very old, but there I had the least problems. GHC had to be compiled manually there). The system where this happens is an Ubuntu Studio 14.04. The other systems use the same stack and cabal versions and have no problems.

Does anybody have an idea, of what happens here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a ghc 8.2+ issue, so you may prefer to stay on 8.0.2 for the time being to avoid it.
(I think Fedora 28 and NixOS have patches for it.)

See https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4728 for more details.